# Handling multiple Primitive items inside a glTF2 Mesh?

Tags: animation, opengl-es, mesh, skin, gltf

I am developing a small app using OpenGL ES and the glTF reference loader library (c#) on a Xamarin Android based Visual Studio project.

Right now, I am trying to build my own class structure for organizing the models' data. I read the specs, and the skinning tutorial was very helpful, but now I have a question concerning the meshes and skins array:

**Question:**

This is an excerpt of the model's Skin section:

```
"skins" : [
    {
        "inverseBindMatrices" : 115,
        "joints" : [
            6,
            7,
            8,
            9,
            10,
            11,
            12,
            13,
            14,
            15,
            16,
            17,
            18,
            19,
            20,
            21,
            22,
            23,
            24,
            25,
            26,
            27,
            28,
            29,
            30,
            31,
            32,
            33,
            34,
            35,
            36,
            37,
            38,
            39,
            40,
            41,
            42,
            43,
            44,
            45,
            46
        ],
        "skeleton" : 0
    },
```

The whole model has 5 Meshes (with multiple Primitives) and several bones/joints. However the **item count** of Skins in the glTF file is way higher than 5! How can this be?! I thought that for each Mesh that is controlled by an armature, there is a Skin? Why are there so many more than 5? Is it because of the multiple primitives? But why are there so many inverseBindMatrices?

It seems to me that there are many pitfalls for a newbie like me. The tutorials are a good starting point, but the examples shown there are so minimalistic, that everything is easy. However, real world models taken from any website are far more complicated than this.

Maybe someone can help me out?

P.S.:
The model I talk about can be found at
[Dropbox link to glTF file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jc7k7jcipihbl5c/littlegirl.gltf?dl=0)

Comment: If the model contains more Skins than Meshes, that's surprising – all Primitives in a Mesh should share the same Skin. Either (1) the exporter of this model made a mistake, or (2) the extra skins are there for some other reason, and can be ignored. In some (usually app-specific) cases you might want to export skins that aren't attached to any Mesh, just to do something with them later.

Comment: Could this be "helpers" from a Blender model? I am no expert at making 3d models, but I think I saw some dashed lines going from the world center to various parts (maybe bones?) of the model. I do not know what  is their purpose but maybe the exporter thinks they are important...

Comment: I'd try a newer version of the Blender exporter – https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO (which is included with Blender 2.8 automatically). If that doesn't work you may want to file a bug on the repository.